# Use jquery.parseHTML() to parse an html string , change data and get back to string

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery parseHTML to load into a DOM then search a keyword and put a span tag with class around them and then want to get it back into a string and insert within the main string

```
    var mainStr = '<div>... a long html ...</div>'
```

Following is a part of the html main string. I have the position where I will insert it back into main string after some changes.

```
    var str ='<span></span> Here is <a href="someurl">xxxxx </a> a presentation of certain statements';

    var myHtml = $.parseHTML(str);
   var keyword = 'presentation'.
   $.each(myHtml, function (i, el) {
   if (el.nodeName == '#text') {
      var loc = el.nodeValue.search(keyword);
   if(loc >0)
      el.nodeValue = el.nodeValue.replace(keyword, "<span class='redColor'>" + keyword + "</span>");
     });
```

Problem is how do I get myHtml object  back as  a string such as:

```
 <span></span> Here is <a href="someurl">xxxxx </a> a <span class="redColor">presentation</span> of certain statements'
```

to insert into the mainHtml string.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should not update the node value of a text node with html content, it will not get parsed.

Instead you can replace the text node with the updated html structure like

```js
var str = '<span></span> Here is <a href="someurl">xxxxx </a> a presentation of certain statements';
var keyword = 'presentation';
var myHtml = $('<div />', {
  html: str
});

myHtml.contents().contents().addBack().each(function() {
  if (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    var loc = this.nodeValue.search(keyword);
    if (loc > 0) {
      var $tmp = $('<div />', {
        html: this.nodeValue.replace(keyword, "<span class='redColor'>" + keyword + "</span>")
      })
      $(this).replaceWith($tmp.contents());
    }
  }
})
var html = myHtml.html();
$('#result').text(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```